# SQL Update query with group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Name         type       Age
-------------------------------
Vijay          1        23
Kumar          2        26
Anand          3        29
Raju           2        23
Babu           1        21
Muthu          3        27
--------------------------------------
```

Write a query to update the name of maximum age person in each type into 'HIGH'.

And also please tell me, why the following query is not working

```
update table1 set name='HIGH' having age = max(age) group by type;
```

Comment: update ta a1
inner join (select type ty,max(age) mage from ta) a2
on a1.type = a2.ty and a1.age = a2.mage
set name='HIGH';

Even the above code also not working

Answer (score 112):

I have changed the script from Derek and it works for me now (MySQL):

```
UPDATE table1 AS t 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT type,max(age) mage FROM table1 GROUP BY type) t1 
ON t.type = t1.type AND t.age = t1.mage 
SET name='HIGH'
```

Comment: This is the form you'll need for MySQL. The form with 'FROM' in the update section does not work.

Comment: No need to say `INNER` `JOIN`, just `JOIN` is sufficient. In MySQL a JOIN is INNER by default.

Comment: This works provided `table1` is not a `TEMPORARY TABLE`. If it is, you run into [bug 10327](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10327).

Comment: Downside: This materializes the entire t1 table even if there is an outer `where` clause.

Comment: @EoghanM indeed. If you don't want that, you need to `SELECT` into a `TEMPORARY TABLE` using the `GROUP BY` first, and then in the `UPDATE` only `JOIN` that `TEMPORARY TABLE`.

Comment: What if we want to set the type of person having second highest age as something like `SECOND_HIGH`. How to do it?

Comment: @DamianYerrick - workaround for that documented limitation of mysql: create a second, identical, temp table: `create temporary table t2 select * from t1;`. Then use each table once in the query.

Comment: “and it works for me now”—Using what SQL implementation? MySQL? Just curious since it would be nice to make a note of that in the answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can't use group by directly in an update statement. It'll have to look more like this:

```
update t
set name='HIGH'
from table1 t
inner join (select type,max(age) mage from table1 group by type) t1
on t.type = t1.type and t.age = t1.mage;
```

Comment: Error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from ta t3
inner join (select type,max(age) mage from ta group by type) t1
on ' at line 3

Comment: @Surendhar Try to put `inner join` before `set`: `UPDATE table1 AS t INNER JOIN (SELECT type,max(age) mage FROM table1 GROUP BY type) t1
ON t.type = t1.type AND t.age = t1.mage SET name='HIGH'`

Comment: Why does this have so many upvotes. Isn't it syntactically wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Since I looked-up this response and found it a little bit confusing to read, I experimented to confirm that the following query *does* work, confirming Svetlana's highly-upvoted original post:

```
update archives_forum f
inner join ( select forum_id, 
    min(earliest_post) as earliest, 
    max(earliest_post) as latest 
  from archives_topic 
    group by forum_id 
  ) t 
  on (t.forum_id = f.id)
set f.earliest_post = t.earliest, f.latest_post = t.latest;
```

Now you know ... and so do I.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a semi-join:

```
SQL> UPDATE table1 t_outer
  2     SET NAME = 'HIGH'
  3   WHERE age >= ALL (SELECT age
  4                       FROM table1 t_inner
  5                      WHERE t_inner.type = t_outer.type);

3 rows updated

SQL> select * from table1;

NAME             TYPE AGE
---------- ---------- ----------
HIGH                1 23
HIGH                2 26
HIGH                3 29
Raju                2 23
Babu                1 21
Muthu               3 27

6 rows selected
```

Your query won't work because you can't compare an aggregate and a column value directly in a group by query. Furthermore you can't update an aggregate.

Comment: Error:
You can't specify target table 't_outer' for update in FROM clause

Comment: What version/DB do you use? I see you have flagged this question with both MySQL and Oracle. This has been tested with Oracle 10.2.0.3.

Comment: Now I m testing it in Mysql 5.0.67

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
update table1 set name='HIGH' having age in(select max(age) from table1 group by type);
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'having age in(select max(age) from table1 group by type)' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code.

```
Update table1#
inner Join (Select max(age) as age, type from Table1 group by Table1) t ON table.age = t.age#
Set name = 'High'#
```

Answer (score -1):

```
update table1 set Name='HIGH' where Age in(select max(Age) from table1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE table1 SET name = 'HIGH' WHERE age IN (SELECT MAX(age) FROM table1 GROUP BY name)
```

Answer (score -3):

You cannot use a GroupBy clause for an Update Statement. You will have to use a sub query during that time

```
Update table1
Set name = 'High'
From table1 
Join (Select max(age), type from Table1 group by Table1) t ON table1.age = t.age
```

Comment: Error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'From table1
Inner Join (Select max(age), type from table1 group by type) t ON table1.age = ' at line 3

Comment: Instead of Inner Join just use Join.

Comment: Why a 'FROM' in a 'UPDATE' !?