# Update Table A from Table B using a maximum vale

Tags: mysql, updates

I have a query that will updated FieldX in Table A from FieldY in TableB when two given fields match in both tables.  I have used it successfully before however in this case TableB has mutliple records that match TableA match field (ID) and I want to pick the record in TableB that has the highest value in FIeld Z.

This is what I have now

```
Update2 `TableA` AS T1 Inner Join `TableB` As T2
On T2.`Ref_ID` = T1.`ID`
Set T1.`FieldX` = T2.`FieldY` where TableA bla bla bla
```

I'm trying to add something to the 'On' line that will say in effect "using the records found that match T2.Ref_ID which has the highest value in Fieldz'

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Update query with group by clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898935/sql-update-query-with-group-by-clause) (that it is the max of the same table there, or of another table here, does not matter).

Comment: I did a brute force solution by making a new table from tableB using Select *, Max(FieldZ) group by FieldX (the field I am trying to update TableA with) and ran the original query on it but would love to know how to combine into one query. Thanks!

Comment: just join on that query as a derived table. as in the link I provided: (`UPDATE t1 JOIN (SELECT refId, MAX(fld) as maxfld FROM t2 GROUP BY refId) derived ON derived.refid=t1.id SET t1.field=derived.maxfld`)