# MySQL SUM(GROUP BY)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add up columns where the ID are the same. I'm new to MySQL but it appears that `Group By` is what I need.

Here is my attempt but it gives me a syntax error

|SiteID|StaffID|Holiday|Total

```
Update SiteStaff
SET Total = SUM(h.Holiday) 
GROUP BY h.StaffID
```

Comment: see this post. you cant directly use group by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898935/sql-update-query-with-group-by-clause

Comment: what is `h.`? Thats not coming from anywhere.

Comment: It had it in an example i looked at. I assumed it was a group name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have a holiday table.  If so, you want a query that uses `join` with `update`, and looks something like this:

```
Update SiteStaff ss LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT h.StaffId, SUM(h.holiday) as total
        FROM Holidays h
        GROUP BY h.StaffID
       ) h
       ON ss.StaffId = h.StaffId
    SET ss.Total = COALESCE(t.total, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be following reasons of the error:-

1. You have used `h.Holiday`in your code. So what is `h` here ?
2. Second reason may be you have to use separate code to find the SUM first and the UPDATE the table.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out from looking at more examples

```
UPDATE SiteStaff p, (SELECT StaffID, SUM(Holiday) as mysum
 FROM SiteStaff GROUP BY StaffID) as s

    SET p.Total = s.mysum
    WHERE p.StaffID = s.StaffID
```